# Querying columnar data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns, bigdata

I have a table structured as shown below

```
CustimerId  Name Store    Bill  Item1  Item2  Item3

1           A    StoreA   100           Y
2           A    StoreB   200    N              Y
3           B    StoreA   300    N
4           C    StoreC   400    Y      N       Y
```

Now I want to make one column based on the values in columns Item1, Item2, Item3 which is as below.

```
CustimerId  Name Store    Bill  BoughtAnySpecialItem

1           A    StoreA   100    Y
2           A    StoreB   200    Y
3           B    StoreA   300    N
4           C    StoreC   400    Y
```

This means if any of the value in columns through Item1 to Item3 is 'Y' I want to make it 'Y' otherwise 'N'. The Item columns are more and or of different name(not like Item-X).

I need the query to do this. Can anyone suggest the best way to do this in SQL server? or at least point me to the right resource. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `case` statement to do that, something like this:

```
case when Item1 = 'Y' or Item2 = 'Y' or Item3 = 'Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end
```

Comment: But my columns are more. there are 200 columns like that. Is there any iterative approach?

Comment: Not really, you can build the same thing as dynamic SQL, but you still need to list the columns you want to check.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have more column's to check you can reverse the `IN` operator

```
 SELECT *,
        CASE WHEN 'Y' in (Item1 , Item2 , Item3) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as BoughtAnySpecialItem
 FROM Yourtable
```

Now you can easily list the column's in `IN` opertaor